# Secure connection fails when adding a custom ILogger class

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core

I want to add my custom logger class to my API. I created a `BitLogger` class that implements `ILogger`, and a `BitLoggerProvider` that implements `ILoggerProvider`. The Logger works and outputs the info in the required format.

But for some reason, when i add this Logger with the `BitLoggerProvider`; any browser connecting to the application fails to setup a secure connection. Removing the `.AddProvider(...)` statement seems to fix this.

At first i thought running `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` might fix it. But this was not the case, maybe firefox was not importing the certificate from windows; but when trying to add an exception for `https://localhost:5001/` firefox tells me that no SSL certificate is being hosted.

The logger works when creating one from code from the provider, but not when injecting it with `.AddProvider(...)`.

Any help is appreciated!

My code:

**BitLogger**

```cs
    public class BitLogger : ILogger
    {

        private readonly List<LogLevel> _levels = new List<LogLevel>()
        {
            LogLevel.Trace,
            LogLevel.Debug,
            LogLevel.Information,
            LogLevel.Warning,
            LogLevel.Error,
            LogLevel.Critical
        };
        private readonly string _root;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public BitLogger(string root, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _root = root;
            _config = config;
        }

        public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
        {
            if (logLevel == LogLevel.None)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return _levels.IndexOf(logLevel) >= _levels.IndexOf(LogLevel.Trace); // TODO
        }

        public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
        {
            // The given level is to low to print.
            if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
            {
                return;
            }

            // The events do not match.
            if (_config.GetValue<int>("EventId") != 0 && _config.GetValue<int>("EventId") != eventId.Id)
            {
                return;
            }

            _Log(logLevel, eventId, state, exception, formatter);
        }

        private void _Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
        {
            var time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff");

            Console.ForegroundColor = logLevel.Color();
            Console.Write($"{time} [{logLevel.Abbreviation()}]");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            Console.Write($" ({eventId.Id}) {_root}".PadRight(_config.GetValue<int>("Padding"), '.'));
            Console.WriteLine($" | {formatter(state, exception)}");
        }
    }

    public static class LogLevelExtensions
    {
        public static string Abbreviation(this LogLevel level)
        {
            return level switch
            {
                LogLevel.Critical => "CRI",
                LogLevel.Error => "ERR",
                LogLevel.Warning => "WRN",
                LogLevel.Information => "INF",
                LogLevel.Debug => "DBG",
                LogLevel.Trace => "TRC",
                _ => "???"
            };
        }

        public static ConsoleColor Color(this LogLevel level)
        {
            return level switch
            {
                LogLevel.Critical => ConsoleColor.DarkRed,
                LogLevel.Error => ConsoleColor.Red,
                LogLevel.Warning => ConsoleColor.Yellow,
                LogLevel.Information => ConsoleColor.Green,
                LogLevel.Debug => ConsoleColor.DarkCyan,
                LogLevel.Trace => ConsoleColor.White,
                _ => ConsoleColor.Gray
            };
        }
    }
```

**BitLoggerProvider**

```cs
    public class BitLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, BitLogger> _loggers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, BitLogger>();

        public BitLoggerProvider(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
        {
            return _loggers.GetOrAdd(categoryName, name => new BitLogger(name, _config));
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _loggers.Clear();
        }
    }
```

**Startup**

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyOrigin();
                });
            });
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddLogging(builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .ClearProviders()
                    .AddDebug()
                    .AddProvider(new BitLoggerProvider(Configuration));
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is an odd one.

The solution was in the `BitLogger` class, in the `.BeginScope()` method to be exact. I forgot to actually implement this method, but for some reason it was not throwing the `NotImplementedException` that was declared in the body. No stacktrace related to this exception could be found anywhere. Maybe because the exception could not be logged, because the logger threw the exception?

Anyway... Changing `throw new NotImplementedException();` to `return null;` fixes this issue.